# How do I render DateTime after it passes through Json

Tags: c#, .net, html, json, datetime

Our C# DateTime property comes through Json like this:

```
/Date(1450674000000)/
```

How do we make that properly formatted as a date so we can display it in our HTML Tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lazarus suggested you could format it to a string representation of the date before serializing. You might need to add a new string property though. (i'm assuming you don't need the time component of the date object)

formatting could be done as shown below.

```
string dateStr = dateObject.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"); // format depends on your need or preference
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get the error - No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest formating it before you serialise it to Json.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?